# syntax and parse error

Tags: c, syntax-error

i keep getting a syntax error on line 9 and parse errors on lines 31, 32, 33, and 38...and i dont know why. Can anyone help me?

```
#include stdio.h<> <-----there are all correct in the code but don't show on here
#include stdlib.h<>
#include math.h<> 

int hamlength;
int pbit;
int hamcode;

String char  *hamming = NULL;

void enter_params(){
    printf("Enter length of the Hamming code:_\n");
      scanf("%d",&hamlength);
 printf("Enter the parity(0=even, 1=odd):_\n");
      scanf("%d",&pbit);
    hamming = (char *)malloc(hamlength * sizeof(char));
}

void free_memory(){
if (hamming != NULL)
    free (hamming);
return;
}

 1. List item

void correct_hamming(){
int errorBit=0;
int currentBit;
int i;
int j;
int k;
printf("Enter the Hamming Code:_\n");
scanf("%s", hamming);
for(i = 1, i < hamlength; i = i * 2){
for(j = i; j < hamlength; j += 2 * i){
for(k = j; k < hamlength && k < currentBit; k++){
        currentBit = currentBit ^ hamming [hamlength - k];
        if (k != i)
        currentBit = currentBit ^ hamming[hamlength - k];       
}
errorBit += ((currenttBit ^(hamming[hamlength - i] - '0')) + i);
}
}
}
int main(){
      int choice=0;
      while(choice!=3){
         printf("1) Set parameters\n");
         printf("2) Check Hamming Code\n");
         printf("3) Exit\n");        
         printf("Enter selection:_\n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
         switch(choice){
            case 1: enter_params(); 
               break; 
            case 2:  correct_hamming();
               break;
           case 3: printf("dueces!");
                    break;


         }
      }
      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `1. List item` isn't valid C. maybe it's cut&paste error, but that's the "obvious" problem. You should also indicate which lines in the above code are lines 31/32/33/38.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include stdio.h<> <-----there are all correct in the code but don't show on here
#include stdlib.h<>
#include math.h<>
```

You meant

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

?

`String char  *hamming = NULL;`

What is `String` doing here? It is not a C keyword. Remove `String` from that line.
Your code is full of syntax and logic errors.

---

```
 1. List item // should be commented
```

---

`errorBit += ((currenttBit ^(hamming[hamlength - i] - '0')) + i);`

Typo here `currenttBit` should be currentBit

---

`for(i = 1, i < hamlength; i = i * 2)`

Replace `,` with `;`

---

In `main()` function

```
  int choice=0;
  while(choice!=3)
```

When would the user enter his choice?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>    // this is the right way to include header files
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
```

`String` is not valid keyword/datatype of C in `String char  *hamming = NULL;`

`1. List item` is not valid in C.

Answer (score 0):

`String char *` doesn't look right to me. You probably didn't mean to include `String` there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "String" on line 9.

And change this line:

```
for(i = 1, i < hamlength; i = i * 2){
```

To this

```
for(i = 1; i < hamlength; i = i * 2){
```

I'm assuming that in your code "1. List item" isn't really there.